# Yii CDbCriteria - OR and foreach()

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

I have some array of elements

```
$cities = array('Paris', 'London', 'Berlin', 'Vinnitsa');
```

And I need to merge criteria in some case. I use such scope:

```
    public function city($cities){
        foreach ($cities as $city){
            $this->getDbCriteria()->mergeWith(array(
                'condition'=>'city LIKE :num',
                'params'=>array(':num'=>$city),
            ), false);
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

I need to generate something like this:

```
... WHERE ext_id='34' 
      AND (ctiy LIKE 'Paris' OR city LIKE 'London' OR city LIKE 'Berlin' OR city LIKE 'Vinnitsa') 
      AND (....)
```

But instead of it Yii-AR generates:

```
WHERE (
     (some_id= 34) 
    OR 
     (city LIKE 'Paris')
   ) 
  OR (city LIKE ''London'')
```

How can I make single OR  condition in one brackets using `getDbCriteria()->mergeWith()`? 
About custom prepared condition I know, but it is to cumbersome ;)

---

UPD: 2012-06-03:

I've solved the problem like this:

```
$citiesReg = implode('|',$cities); //Convert to REGEXP 

$this->getDbCriteria()->mergeWith(array(
       'condition'=>'city REGEXP :city',
       'params'=>array(':city'=>$citiesReg),
        ));
return $this;
```

For use UTF-8 you additionally need:
 1. To lowercase each element of array mb_strtolower($val,'UTF-8'); before converting to string.
 2. A bit modify the condition: 'condition'=>'LOWER(city) REGEXP :city'

It is because of MySQL lib REGEXP worlks badly with utf-8.

Thanks for participating!

Comment: Have you tried [`CDbCriteria::addInCondition`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addInCondition-detail)?

Comment: "keep the unanswered count low" 
How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Let try [addInCondition](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria/#addCondition-detail), first parameter is condition (e.g 'cite LIKE \'London\' ') and the second is the operator (OR or AND).

You can foreach the array (city) and use addInCondition.

Comment: I've solved that problem like this: 

$citiesStr = implode('|',$cities); //Convert to REGEXP

$this->getDbCriteria()->mergeWith(array(
       'condition'=>'city REGEXP :city',
       'params'=>array(':city'=>$citiesStr),
        ));
return $this;

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](http://code.google.com/p/yii/issues/detail?id=676#c3) about using mergeWith and foreach the array. Maybe it is what kamankily suggest, but using $criteria (not addInCondition)